# Is there a way to get uid of context for a Cloud function written in Java

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function in java triggered by events in the Firebase RTDB.

The documentation for Firebase has not been extended to java yet.But is seems that context generally has the property auth. However for java this doesn't seems to be possible

I can only get resource like in the example below, timestamps and a couple of other properties, but not auth.

```
@Override
    public void accept(String json, Context context) {
        logger.info("Function triggered by change to: " + context.resource());
```

Is there maybe a different way to perform this in java ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an HTTP functions, you can get the auth in the header. This auth authenticate the requester.

In your case, you have a background function, triggered by a Cloud Event. There is no authentication in this case. You have info in the context of the "requester" (the event emitter) but nothing about the "auth" itself.